# Is any imaginary quadratic field equal to $\mathrm{End}(E) \otimes \Bbb Q$ for some $E / \Bbb F_q$?

Tags: elliptic-curves

Let $K$ be an imaginary quadratic field. Is there always a finite field $k$ and an elliptic curve $E$ such that the endomorphism algebra $\mathrm{End}_{\overline k}(E) \otimes \Bbb Q$ is isomorphic to $K$ ?

A refined question would be whether any order $O \subset K$ is isomorphic to $End(E)$ of some $E$ ?

(The analogue for $K=\Bbb Q$ is discussed here:[Is the ring of integers of any imaginary quadratic field equal to $\mathrm{End}(E)$ for some $E / \Bbb Q$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4123182/is-the-ring-of-integers-of-any-imaginary-quadratic-field-equal-to-mathrmend))

I know that $E$ should be ordinary in that case (the supersingular case is known due to Deuring correspondence).

One idea would be to take some $E / \Bbb C$ with CM by $K$, it is then defined over some number field $L$, and then find a prime ideal $Q$ of $O_L$ so that $End(E) \cong End(E \times_{O_L} O_L / Q)$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, from Serge Lang's book *Elliptic Functions* theorem 13.4.12 (Deuring) says the following:
[image: Deuring_Lang]

So it suffices to take a prime integer $q$ that splits in $O_K$ (not necessarily in $O_L$ !) such that $q$ doesn't divide the conductor of the order $End(E) \subset O_K$ (there exist infinitely many such $q$ by Cebotarev, or Frobenius theorem... !), then the reduction of the curve $E / L$ mod $Q$ (where $Q$ is any prime above $q$) has the same endomorphism ring as $E$.

I guess that any order $O \subset O_K$ can be $End(E)$ for some $E$ over a number field (take a suitable complex torus... then CM theory tells us it is defined over $\overline{\Bbb Q}$). But of course, over a given finite field $k$, there are only finitely many possible $End(E)$ for $E/k$. But what about $E / \overline k$ (e.g. this includes all maximal orders in the quaternion algebra $Q_{p, \infty}$ by Deuring)?

Then I guess we have the following:
an order $O$ in an imaginary quadratic field $K$ is the endomorphism ring of some $E / \overline{\Bbb F_p}$ iff the conductor of $O$ is coprime to $p$ (i.e. $O = \Bbb Z + f O_K$ for $gcd(f,p)=1$) and $p$ splits in $K$.

One direction was just proved. The other uses Deuring lifting theorem (13.5.14 in Lang), and combined with part i) of thm 12 above.

Comment: See Theorem 9.10.18 in https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~sgal018/crypto-book/ch9.pdf

Comment: See also http://www.mat.uniroma2.it/~schoof/cubiccurves.pdf thm 4.3 (refers to Waterhouse 1969 thesis)

Comment: Notice that for ordinary E / F_q, we have $End(E) \otimes Q = Q(\sqrt{D})$ where $D= a_q^2 - 4q < 0$ (by Hasse and $D=0$ implies $E$ supersingular). We have $D \geq -4q$, so there are finitely many imag. quad. fields that can occur (and also fin. many orders therein, since there are fin. many E / F_q, for fixed q !).